# Fedora inode bitmap is not in group

Tags: fedora, filesystems, boot

My Fedora 24 just stopped loading. Journalctl states:

```
/dev/mapper/fedora-root: Inode bitmap for group 128 is not in group. (block 33619980)
/dev/mapper/fedora-root: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY: RUN fsck MANUALLY.
fsck failed with error code 4.
```

How can I fix that to get the system running?

Comment: It says to "run fsck manually".  So try booting into Rescue Mode and running `fsck`?  https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/24/html-single/Installation_Guide/index.html#sect-boot-options-rescue

Answer (score 0):

Ran `fsck -y /dev/root/fedora-mapper` and it fixed the problem.